# How to access property of DataGrid ItemsSource object in DataGridRow.CellStyle?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

First of all, let me show you my classes:

```
public class Model
{
    public Model Parent {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Childs {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Partner> Partners {get; set;}
    public bool IsTopElement => Parent == null;
}

public class Partner
{
    public bool IsActive {get; set;}
    public string PartnerRole {get; set;}
    public bool IsCustomer => PartnerRole == "Customer"
}
```

As you can see, `Model`is a hierarchy as it can have a parent and a list of childs. I have a UserControl whose DataContext is set to an instance of `Model`. In this UserControl I have a DataGrid whose ItemsSource is bound to `Partners`. In this DataGrid I have a DataGridCheckBoxColumn that is bound to `IsActive` property of `Partner` object and several DataGridTextColumns.
What I want to achieve is that if the current `Model` object is NOT the top element (has no parent), all `IsActive`-Checkbox cells that belong to a `Partner` entry whose `IsCustomer == True` shall be disabled.
I tried the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Model}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Partners}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsActive}">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Model.IsTopElement}" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ???}"/> <!-- I'd have expected Binding="{Binding IsCustomer}" Value="True" to work, but it doesn't-->
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>             
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem I'm facing now is that I don't have access to the property `IsCustomer` of the `Partner` object in the DataGrid in the second Condition of the MultiDataTrigger. So how can I access this property there? Also, I didn't expect to have access to `IsTopElement` property of `Model` in the first Condition because the ItemsSource of the DataGrid is bound to `Partners` but apparently I have, which is rather confusing to me.
Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `DataGridCell` is a `Partner` object. You could use a `{RelativeSource}` to bind to the parent `UserControl`'s `DataContext`. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsTopElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsCustomer}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I think you misunderstood something. It's not the `IsTopElement` property of `Model` that is giving me trouble but the `IsCustomer` property of the `Partner` object in the DataGridRow that I can't access. I tried your approach though. Unfortunately, `<Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsCustomer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" Value="False"/>` didn't work for my second condition. VS says `DataContext.IsCustomer` cannot be resolved. I can run the application but the desired behaviour is not achieved.

Comment: How do you know which property is giving you trouble? A Partner doesn't have any Model property so why would your first binding work? You are not giving the whole picture here...Since the Partner class has an IsCustomer property, you should be able to bind to this one directly as I showed you.

Comment: How about <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsTopElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Value="False"/>? Should work since Partners and IsTopElement belongs to the same class. At least in the code you have posted here. Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided.

Comment: I played around with your suggestion a bit more and changing the AncestorType to `DataGridRow` did the trick :)
I knew it had to be the second binding that didn't work because without it the Checkboscolumn was disabled as desired.
I edited your answer the way it worked for me and accepted it. Thanks again for your help!